# rewrite rule for htaccess to two seperate directories

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

On a single server i have a directory called app which has angular and another directory called api which has laravel installed.

I have the following for the angular code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app/
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1 [L]
```

which works fine now i need to add another rule where in angular i can use angulars $http to call www.domain.com/api/users and it will point to api/public/index.php which will in turn call the router and forward it to the correct controller

Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a new rule for `/api/users`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api/.+$ /api/public/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!app/).*)$ /app/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Is there a general one for /API/* I'm going to have many routes in /API/ I don't want a new rule for each route

Comment: Clarify that comment with few more examples so that I can suggest something different.

Comment: Do you want any `/api/*` to be forwarded to `/api/public/index.php`?

Comment: I want all calls on API/ to be forwarded to the same router. The index.php is my router which takes the request and sends it to the correct controller

Comment: ok I have already made that change. Did you try updated rules?

Comment: doesnt seem to be working I guess i should make my question more laravel specific

Comment: For which URL it is not working? For testing try: `RewriteRule ^api/.+$ /api/public/index.php [L,NC,R]` in first rule.